# Perform a single server call in lightning instead of multiple calls

Tags: salesforce, apex, aura-framework

In the helper I have methods that each call an @AuraEnabled method in the component controller.

Some of these calls are only during the 'init' event.
From a performance point of view I should make only one call during 'init'.

What is an elegant way of achieving this?

The methods called during 'init' return a list of strings, a decimal, and respectively a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a [custom Apex class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_returning_data.htm) in your controller that encapsulates all of the information you wish to source in a single call from your `init` event:

```
public class InitializationWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled 
    public List<String> myStringList {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled 
    public Decimal myDecimal {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled 
    public String myString {get; set;}
}
```

The, return an instance of this wrapper class from your server-side Apex call to your `init` handler. You only need to make a single round-trip.

Comment: is this approach better than (I found other way in the meantime, didn't get the chance to implement it see wether it works) having one method like

Comment: is this approach better than (I found other way in the meantime, didn't get the chance to implement it to see wether it works) having one @AuraEnabled method that returns - Map<string, List<string?>> - and in the controller var myStringList= response.getReturnValue()['keyString List']; myDecimal= response.getReturnValue()['keyDecimal']; etc.

Comment: @zen I'm not sure there's much difference. There, you'd have to handle types a little differently in Apex, since Decimals would have to be converted to String.

Answer (score 0):

I'd swear you don't have to do anything, no fancy coding, SF would do it for you as part of Aura framework...

Used to work for me like a charm a while ago (in fact even other way around, it was for sure 1 Apex call = all methods I had were using same governor limits, I had to rework some queries)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm

> $A.enqueueAction(action) adds the server-side controller action to the
>   queue of actions to be executed. All actions that are enqueued will
>   run at the end of the event loop. Rather than sending a separate
>   request for each individual action, the framework processes the event
>   chain and batches the actions in the queue into one request. (...) The
>   framework batches the actions in the queue into one server request.
>   The request payload includes all of the actions and their data
>   serialized into JSON. The request payload limit is 4 MB.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_queue.htm

> The framework queues up actions before sending them to the server.
>   This mechanism is largely transparent to you when you’re writing code
>   but it enables the framework to minimize network traffic by batching
>   multiple actions into one request (XHR). The batching of actions is
>   also known as boxcar’ing, similar to a train that couples boxcars
>   together.
>
> The framework uses a stack to keep track of the actions to send to the
>   server. When the browser finishes processing events and JavaScript on
>   the client, the enqueued actions on the stack are sent to the server
>   in a batch.

If this doesn't work as described for you (can you post some code?) and request size is < 4 MB... Maybe they broke something and you've found a platform bug. You're sure you see separate entries in Debug Log? Or in network traffic monitoring in browser?

Maybe you need to play with [background actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_background_actions.htm). I mean this is supposed to work without extra crutches in Apex to bundle multiple calls into one, create complex response wrapper class and every callback unpicks only data it cares about, that's lots of unneccessary code :/